# Remove method in a binary tree

Tags: java, binary-tree, nodes

I'm trying to create a method to remove nodes from a Binary Tree but I am having a problem, it seems to be ok but I have another method for printing all of them and after "deleting" a specific node I use the print method but it prints all of them including the one I've already deleted.

```
public class BinaryTree
{
    Node root;
    Node n;
    private class Node
    {
        public Node f; //father
        public Node right;
        public Node left;
        public int key; // key
        public String Student;
        public int Mark;

        public Node(int key)
        {
            right = null;
            left = null;
            f = null;
            Student = null;
            Mark = 0;
        }
    }

    public void remove()
    {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Which student do you want to delete? Write down his ID.");
        int id = Genio.getInteger();
        n = new Node(id);
        Node temporal = root;
        if(root == null)
        {
            System.out.println("This tree is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            while(temporal != null)
            {
                n.f = temporal;
                if(n.key == temporal.key)
                {

                    if(n.f.right == null && n.f.left == null)
                    {
                        n = null;
                        temporal = null;
                    }

                }
                else if(n.key >= temporal.key)
                {
                    temporal = temporal.right;
                }
                else
                {
                    temporal = temporal.left; 
                }
            }

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Try adding `this.key = key;` to the `Node` constructor. That's just a *bit* important.

Comment: @4castle I've just tried that but nothing changed D: thank anyway!!